# kubernetes on Oracle OCI Always free exec format error

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes

I create a cluster kuberntes using the Shape: VM.Standard.A1.Flex(Ampere arm-based processor)
I'm using terraform [amperetacle](https://github.com/jpetazzo/ampernetacle)

I'm created a golang project and created the Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.18 AS build
COPY ./api /api
WORKDIR /api
COPY . .

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -mod vendor -a -o ./processor ./cmd/processor

FROM alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build /api/processor /app/processor
WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod +x /app/processor
CMD ["./processor"]
```

If I run image it works

But when kubernets run

`exec ./processor: exec format error`

Comment: You say you're using an arm based processor to run the program, but I don't see you setting `GOARCH` anywhere to cross compile for that architecture.

Comment: it works, tks!!